# progressive load and play video from base64 pieces

Tags: html, video, base64, chunks

I have many pieces of a video in base64.

Just that I want is to play the video progressively as I receive them.

```
    var fileInput = document.querySelector('input#theInputFile');//multiple

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var files = fileInput.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = fileInput.files[i]
        fileLoaded(file, 0, 102400, file.size);
    };

    e.preventDefault();
});

videoA=[];
function fileLoaded(file, ini, end, size) {
    if (end>size){end=size}
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onloadend = function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
            var piece = e.target.result;
            display(piece.replace('data:video/mp4;base64,', ''));
        }
    };

    var blob = file.slice(ini, end, file.type);
    fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
    var init = end;
    var endt = init+end;
      if (end<size){
        fileLoaded(file, init, end, size);  
      }

}
```

Trying to display the video by chunks:

```
    var a=0;
    function display(vid, ini, end) {
        videoA.push(vid);
        $('#video').attr('src','data:video/mp4;base64,'+videoA[a]);
        a++;
    }
```

I know this is not the way but I`m trying to search and any response adjust to that I'm searching.
Even I'm not sure if it is possible.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I've tried to play the chunks one by one and the first one is played well but the rest of them give the error: 
"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found".
If I could make the chunks to base64 correctly it's enough for me

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is to solve the creation of base64 pieces from the original uploaded file in the browser that can be played by an html5 player

So I've put another question asking for that.
[Chunk video mp4 file into base64 pieces with javascript on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45168462/chunk-video-mp4-file-into-base64-pieces-with-javascript-on-browser)